# xpath doesn't match if the item has one or more child elements

Tags: php, xpath

I have a method that looks like this:

```
function braces(DOMElement $node){
    $path   = $node->getNodePath();
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($node->ownerDocument);
    $nodes = $xpath->query($path . '[*=(contains(., "{{") and contains(., "}}"))]');

    var_dump($nodes);
}
```

I have created the following two test cases:

#### Test Case 1

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<div data-id="{{cat}}">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>',LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

braces($dom->documentElement);
```

The `var_dump()` on this one does not find the attribute with `{{` and `}}`.

Here is **test case 1's** resulting output:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#4 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

#### Test Case 2

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<div data-id="{{cat}}"></div>',LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

braces($dom->documentElement);
```

When removing the child `a` element, the `var_dump()` now can find the attribute with `{{` and `}}`.

Here is **test case 2's** resulting output:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

So, my question is why can't it find the value when the item has children?

Answer (score 0):

Take another look at your predicate

```
*=(contains(., "{{") and contains(., "}}"))
```

This is an equality comparison with two operands. The right-hand operand is a boolean (A and B is always boolean). XPath 1.0, therefore, forces the left-hand operand to be a boolean as well. `"*"` selects the children of the context node; `boolean(*)` is true if that node-set is non-empty, that is, if the context node has one or more children.

So your equality comparison is true if either (a) the node has children and contains braces, or (b) the node has no children and does not contain braces.

What do I mean by contains here? The expression `contains(., 'x')` is true if the string value of the node contains `'x'` as a substring. The string value of a node derives from the children/descendants of the node; it takes no account of attributes. Because it ignores attributes, your `contains()` test is false in both cases, so the predicate as a whole is true only if the left-hand operand is also false, that is, if the node has no children.

Comment: After many reads of your answer it started to make some sense, but here is what I came up with... does this look like a better query? `@.=(contains(., "{{") and contains(., "}}"))` when tested, it seems to work...

Comment: No, it's total rubbish. You're just guessing, aren't you? Get a reference book and read it, you won't get this right by guesswork.

Comment: Not really. Based on what you said, about the asterisk, I used a "@." To signifying an attribute

Comment: (a) `@` must be followed by a node test. `.` is not a node test. Any XPath reference will tell you that. A node test is typically an attribute name or a wildcard (`*`). (b) you're still trying to compare a node to a boolean with that `=` operator. You want a predicate: something like `*[contains(@id, '{{')]`.